# Is it safe to use primary keys(UUID) in forms on one webpage?

Tags: django

In one django view, I create a form. And I save a list of uuid to a char field of form. After the form is submitted, I will get the list of uuid.

```
class ContactForm(forms.Form):
    list_uuids = forms.CharField()
```

In html,

```
<input type="hidden" name="object_pk" value="sf332d19-103a-4c90-bc53-f159954913rt">
```

It works fine. But I am questioned about the security. Is it ok to release a lot of uuid to any user?

Refer to the question `Why not expose a primary key?`
https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/218306/why-not-expose-a-primary-key.

It is true the uuid to identify the data in database. But in webpage, I have to identify the objects, eg users. And uuid is the only info to identify the object.

Or should I encrypt all the uuids to make my website safe enough?

Comment: It's somewhat unclear what you mean by "safe" in this context. It'd help if you shared some code so we have more specifics; without that, it's going to be hard to give you an answer.

Comment: @jacobian Thanks for the suggestion. I will make it more clear. It is not a programming problem, it is more about the design or theory part.

Comment: Personally I would avoid exposing (large) parts of the database. This is not a "direct" security risk. But it gives a hacker information about what are valid ids in the database. Which can be valuable.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Thanks for the commend. Is there another way to implement it without exposing the information of uuids?

Comment: @user18481: well if these are the uids of the objects of the hacker ("his/her" objects) then there is no problem, but in case you return *all* (or a huge set), you should simply try to filter the data, such that only relevant uuids show up.

Comment: What do you mean byt this 'I have to identify the objects, eg users. And uuid is the only info to identify the object.' What have you tried to do ?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Thanks. Maybe the only solution is to encrypt it since I can not stop hacker filter multiple times and get all data.

Comment: @Rarblack Yes, the only thing does not changer for an object eg in my case, user, is uuid since user can change their name ...

Comment: I understood this but why do you need to store the uuids? If you just need to save them when some action is triggered or some data is being saved in some field you can simply use signals.

Comment: @Rarblack For instance, someone select user list and sending them emails, I cannot just use signals. I need to know who are selected.

Comment: Then I would suggest either using ForeignKey or ManyToMany field to provide choice option of users to send.

Comment: @Rarblack I do not get the difference between using manytomany filed or not.